# Recursion method does not work to add element into arrayList

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

I am trying to create a recursion of an *ArrayList*（`friends`) to fill up another *ArrayList* (`recommendations`). However, the recursion method does not work. The question is as below:

> How should we go about recommending new friends? We’ll take the approach of recommending all of our friends’ friends and our friends’ friends’ friends, and so on. This is a perfect opportunity to use recursion – we can create a getRecommendations method that takes a FacebookUser as an argument. The method should return an ArrayList that contains all of the friends of the FacebookUser that is passed into it plus the result of calling the same getRecommendations method on all of that FacebookUser’s friends. Be careful not to add anyone to the list of recommendations if they are already on it – that could lead to an infinite loop.

```
public ArrayList<FacebookUser> getRecommendations(FacebookUser user){
    ArrayList<FacebookUser> recommendations = new ArrayList<FacebookUser>();

    for (FacebookUser friend : user.getFriends()) {
        getRecommendations(friend, recommendations);
    }

    if (!recommendations.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Recommended Friends");
        System.out.println(recommendations);
    }
    return recommendations;
}

public void getRecommendations(FacebookUser friend, ArrayList<FacebookUser> recommendations) {
    if (friend != null && friend.getFriends() != null && !friend.getFriends().isEmpty()) {
        for (FacebookUser friendFriend : friend.getFriends()) {
            if (!recommendations.contains(friendFriend)) {
                recommendations.add(friendFriend);
                System.out.println(recommendations); //test
                getRecommendations(friendFriend, recommendations);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the recursion under the first `getRecommendations()` method to work and brings it down to the second `getRecommendations()` method. However, it skipped the following part:

```
getRecommendations(friend, recommendations);
```

Comment: "it skipped the part" - What was skipped, exactly?

Comment: line 5, getRecommendations(friend, recommendations);

Comment: When I call the second getRecommendations method, it does not go down there.

Comment: If the overloaded `getRecommendations` method (with two parameters) is never called, then that means that `user.getFriends()` returns an empty `Iterable`.

Comment: I wonder why it is not called? I have both FacebookUser and ArrayList<FacebookUser> passed into that overloaded constructor

Comment: Like I said, the body of the for-loop will never be entered if `user.getFriends()` is empty

Comment: i did a sysout of `user.getFriends()` , there are elements in there.

Comment: Then the method **is** invoked. You'll need to use your debugger and figure out which conditions aren't met.

Comment: I think you should set a level to stop recursion, in facebook everybody has frieds.

Comment: @JacobG. i checked and my 'for (FacebookUser friendFriend : friend.getFriends())' part contains only [ ]. But at other part of my code it has something in there. I wonder why..

Comment: You might want to provide the sample "friend graph" you run your program with. Otherwise it's hard to tell what's wrong. It is expected that in some cases `friend.getFriends()` is empty, when you reach somebody who is a, well, loner. :-)

Comment: You have probably confused yourself because of the recursion. Since you are recursively getting friends' friends' friends' friends' friends' friends' friends, it will at some point stop having friends (or you would have a stackoverflow exception), so the topmost stack would be called by the 2nd topmost stack's `getRecommendations(friendFriend, recommendations);` that would exit upon the `if` check.

Comment: This is the second Java question I’ve seen today from a new(ish) user with a `FacebookUser` class. Deadline looming perchance?

Comment: You call `friend.getFriends()` three times. Make the second method private. The second method does depth first search. You probably want breadth first instead.

Comment: @MTCoster yes but I've been working on it for the entire week. Won't ask if I have another solution...